# Find all quadratic residues $a \mod 17$ with $1 \leq a \leq 17$.

Tags: number-theory

Find all quadratic residues $a \mod 17$ with $1 \leq a \leq 17$.

I found an answer that says the quadratic resides are $1,2,4,8,9,13,15,16$. But, from my understanding, a quadratic residue is a perfect square, and some of these are not perfect squares. What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: $2$ isn't a square? Of course not! But $6^2=36\equiv 2\pmod{17}$, so $2$ **is** a square modulo $17$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Square all of the numbers between $1$ and $17$ and *reduce them modulo $17$.*

Comment: I did...well, not all of them but for example, 2 is not a square of any integer. So why is $2$ included?

Comment: @PBJ Not all of them???

Comment: Do all of them and then REDUCE THEM MODULO 17.

Comment: Oh...I see the point. So, maybe there is some integer which, when squared, will reduce to 2.  I thought that the numbers listed were the numbers to square, or something like that. But I wasn't going to do all of them until i figured out whether i was doing it correctly. I think I get it now. Thank you

Comment: @PBJ so, for example, what do you get when you reduce $5^2 \pmod {17}?$

Comment: @Will Jagy, I get 8.

Comment: @PBJ well, there you go. You can find all the quadratic residues $\pmod {17}$ by continuing. For one of your other questions, you can find the residues $\pmod {23}$ the same way, then the residues $\pmod {31}$

Comment: A trick known only to the initiated (of which @WillJagy is one) is that reducing $(n-x)^2$ modulo $n$ gives the same number as reducing $x^2$ modulo $n.$ That cuts your work in two!

Comment: @Will Jagy, thank you very much sir. I am getting these concepts now for sure :)